# Component-wise limit of vector-valued function

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

The following problem is from *Calculus on Manifolds* by Michael Spivak.

> If $f:A\to\mathbb{R}^m$ and and $a\in A$, show that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=b$ if and only if $\lim_{x\to a}f^i(x)=b^i$ for all $i=1,\dots,m$. Here, $f^i(x)$ and $b^i$ represent the $i$-th component of each vector.

**My attempt:**
($\implies$) By the definition of a limit, we have that for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|x-a|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-b|<\epsilon$. 
Using the definition of the Euclidean norm, we have 
\begin{align*}
|f(x)-b| & = \sqrt{\langle f(x)-b,f(x)-b\rangle}
\\ & = \sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^m|f^i(x)-b^i|^2}<\epsilon
\\ \implies & \sum\limits_{i=1}^m|f^i(x)-b^i|^2 <\epsilon^2
\\ \implies & |f^i(x)-b^i|<\epsilon
\end{align*} 
* *Not sure if this last line works.*

($\impliedby$) By the definition of a limit, for each $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|x-a|<\delta$ implies $|f^i(x)-b^i|<\epsilon$ for each $i=1,\dots,m$. Then, 
\begin{align*}
|f(x)-b| & = \sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^m|f^i(x)-b^i|^2}
\\ & <\sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^m\epsilon^2}
\\ & = \epsilon\sqrt{m}
\end{align*}
Thus $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=b$.

**Not sure if everything I did works, would appreciate a quick proof-read.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second part you can only say that for each $i$ you get a $\delta_i$ such that .....You then have to take $\delta$ to be the minimum of the $\delta_i$'s. 
The first part is correct and you are using the simple fact that in a sum of nonnegative numbers each term is less than or equal to the sum.